# Invoking a method of the key object of a dictionary using lambda expressions

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

If I have something like:

```
Dictionary<SomeObject, SomeOtherObject> _mydictionary
```

and `SomeObject` has a method: `SomeMethod()`

How do I call the method `SomeMethod()` using lambda expressions without converting the keys to a list and doing a ForEach. The `ToList()` makes it too expensive. Or, the equivalent in lambda to:

```
foreach(SomeObject o in _mydictionary.Keys)
  o.SomeMethod();
```

???

I tried:

```
_mydictionary.ToList().ForEach(x => x.SomeMethod());
```

but this seems too expensive with the `ToList();`

Comment: FWIW, I'd stick with your `foreach` loop. It's perfectly clear and concise.

Comment: For the curious out there here is a plausible explanation for why IEnumerable doesn't have the **ForEach** extension method: [“foreach” vs “ForEach”](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx)

Comment: ForEach() is on List<T> and not an extension method for IEnumerable<T>, so if you don't write your own ext method, yes you'll have to use ToList() or foreach

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in extension method to invoke a collection of `void` methods, whether delegates or members of a collection of objects.

You can, however, create one relatively easily:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T> action)
{
  foreach (var item in items) action(item);
}
```

Now you can call all those methods in a LINQish way:

```
_mydictionary.Keys.ForEach(x => x.SomeMethod());
```

You already have access to the `.Keys` collection property on `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>`; you don't need to call `.ToList()` anywhere.

---

If `SomeMethod()` is a function, and you want to create a result set, then you can use the built-in extension method `Select()`:

```
var results = _mydictionary.Keys.Select(x => x.SomeMethod());
```

As George rightly points out, `SomeMethod()` will not be invoked unless needed -- that is, unless you actually use the results by iterating over them. This can avoid the overhead of creating a new collection, but one should take care to avoid multiple enumerations.

Comment: lol, great minds... I'll delete my (almost exact same answer) but you might find that you need to add a Cast to the Keys collection.

Comment: @TimJarvis I don't understand why one would need to cast the Keys. A generic `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>` will have a keys collection of type `ICollection<TKey>` and a values collection of type `ICollection<TValue>`.

Comment: That leads to almost the same problem.  `Select` needs a return value (if `SomeMethod` is void, your code won't compile) in which case it creates *another collection*...

Comment: @PeterRitchie Did you read my answer? It includes both `void` and function scenarios. *If `SomeMethod()` is a function…*. I'd also add that `Select` does not create another collection in and of itself, as it is lazy-evaluated.

Comment: @jay Yes, I *did* read you answer, hence the comment about creating *another collection*. And you added the note about `void` **after my comment**. OP said nothing about creating *another collection* of types returned by the function (whose existence seems specious).  If the OP is concerned about `ToList()` that *is being used*, the OP would be concerned about another collection *that isn't being used*--especially if it's a collection of `null`s.

Comment: @PeterRitchie You are mistaken. I started with the answer in the context of `void`, and added the information about `Select` for completeness because the OP does not indicate whether `SomeMethod` is a function. The edit history bears this out.

Comment: @jay If you "started in the context of `void`", your first post had `_mydictionary.Keys.ForEach(x => x.SomeMethod())` which would be a compile error if `SomeMethod` returned void. Your 2nd and 3rd revisions had the same code.  Your 4th revision (after my comment) detailed "`void` method".

Comment: Ok, so there is no way to do it without the ToList()??

Comment: How about if I want something like:
_mydictionary.ToList().ForEach(e => e.Key.SomeProperty = e.Value);

Comment: @user1615606 You can use the extension method I give in the answer and skip `ToList()`.

Comment: @PeterRitchie Please read the entire answer. The whole point is that you use the `ForEach` extension method to invoke `void` methods. That was initially and remains the core of my answer. There is no compiler error. The extension method implementation is in the answer; try it yourself.

Comment: public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T> action)
{
  foreach (var item in items) action(item);
}

and 

_mydictionary.Keys.ForEach(x => x.SomeMethod()); 

does not work!!!

Comment: Select() won't do anything unless you enumerate your "ignored" enumerable sequence

Comment: @user1615606 actually the ForEach extension method works great on the Keys property

Comment: @GeorgeTsiokos Good point! I'm going to take that whole bit out; it only muddies the waters on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Reactive Extensions (Rx)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609):

```
var keys = _mydictionary.Keys;
// convert the enumerable sequence of keys to an observable sequence
var observableKeys = keys.ToObservable ();
// invoke SomeMethod for each key
await observableKeys.ForEachAsync (obj =>
    obj.SomeMethod ());
```

This code will execute without blocking calls enumerating the sequence prior to calling the 1st SomeMethod, and it won't allocate another collection.

Unfortunately [we're waiting for a new release](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/651edc24-452a-44ba-8f5a-46129bcea559) of the Interactive Extensions (Ix) that would have exactly the same functionality without the need to convert from an enumerable to an observable sequence.

Comment: Wasn't IX released a couple months after Windows 8 client SDK?  @GeorgeTsiokos: is it time to refresh the answer?